# Resizing Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, navbar

I am creating a website using Bootstrap and want to resize the Navbar height when the browser screen is min-width: 268, I am using a media query to do this but for some reason the media query changes the height of the Navbar before the screen has been made smaller, can someone please help, code is below.

```
     .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: transparent;
    height: 105px;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 268px) {
    .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: "The media query changes the height of the Navbar before the screen has been made smaller." - Yes, because this will get applied when the width is >= 268px. Are you sure you didn't mean to use max-width?

Comment: can you give us a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this style to apply when the width is LESS than 286px, use `max-width`. Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 268px) {
    .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    }
}
```